# Cloud Foundry Certified Provider vendor lock-in?

Tags: cloud-foundry, lock-in

I'm trying to figure out, how the *Cloud Foundry Certified Provider* Program is tackling vendor lock-in. I've read that it enables Developers to migrate their apps to another certified provider without bigger problems. I'm not sure how this works since theres is nothing written in the requiremets about supported languages or services. 
It seams to me, that this certification only guarantees easy porability for statelass apps which doesn't consume any other services.
Am I right with this assumption?

[Cloud Foundry launches PaaS certification to combat vendor lock-in](http://www.businesscloudnews.com/2015/12/17/cloud-foundry-launches-paas-certification-to-combat-vendor-lock-in/)

Comment: why the downvote? Interesting question. I see also the database hosting as vendor lock. Try to migrate a 300 GB MongoDB instance to other provider, it's not impossible but difficult.

Comment: As a developer, I look at the services that a CloudFoundry provider offers in the marketplace as a convenience (as the platform provider, they would be a competitive advantage).  They're easy to provision and use in conjunction with my apps.  It's *not* required for me to use them though.  If, for example, I don't like the MySQL service provider in the marketplace, I'm free to find and use my own provider.  I would just wire this into my app as a user provided service.

Comment: As far as migrating service providers, say from one MongoDb provider to another MongoDb provider, it's no more difficult than migrating service providers w/out CloudFoundry.  With regard to services, the platform just makes it easy and fast to provision and easy for an app to get the credentials.  The platform doesn't provide any functionality to work with services (i.e. insert, update, migrate or do anything to the data w/in the service).

Comment: Using a user provide services has nothing to do with latency.  A UPS simply a way to pass in credentials to your app.  If the latency is too high to your service provider, pick a different service provider or run your own service in a location that has better network latency.  Alternatively, if the latency to your favorite service provider is too high from your Cloud Foundry provider, pick a new Cloud Foundry provider :)  That's the beauty of having an open platform, you can move amongst them with very little effort.